# DNS problems, IPv6 not working on ubuntu 14.04; windows or an ubuntu live cd works fine

Tags: networking

Ubuntu 14.04 was working fine yesterday. I think I installed some routine updates. Today when I booted up my computer (a thinkpad x220 laptop) I could not get a wired internet connection (there were arrow symbols in the top bar indicating a connection, but I could not connect to a webpage or `ping` google). However I was able to connect wirelessly to my cell phone, using its tethering feature.

I rebooted into windows 8 and it worked fine (it still does, I am writing this post on windows). Things also worked fine with an ubuntu live cd. Then when I rebooted back into ubuntu I could not even connect wirelessly to my phone anymore.

I have tried deleting the connection from the network manager and reconnecting. I have also tried disabling wireless (I have a hardware switch for that on my laptop). Neither made a difference.

I am in an apartment complex. I assume there is a router somewhere but I have no access to it, just an Ethernet port in the wall.

EDIT: I discovered that if I disable IPv6 I can ping IP addresses (but still not access websites). The normal way to add DNS servers (through "edit connections") didn't work, but I was able to make it work by creating the file /etc/resolv.conf with the line `nameserver 8.8.8.8`. But I'd still prefer a solution that doesn't require me to disable IPv6.

Here is the output of `ifconfig -a`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:de:f1:8c:99:da  
          inet6 addr: 2001:1620:2018:1c:d101:c3c8:2dca:19a2/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:1620:2018:1c:f2de:f1ff:fe8c:99da/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::f2de:f1ff:fe8c:99da/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1877 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:148 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:123802 (123.8 KB)  TX bytes:29027 (29.0 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f2500000-f2520000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5784 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5784 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:439348 (439.3 KB)  TX bytes:439348 (439.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:de:2b:0d:90:8a  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:101 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1785 (1.7 KB)  TX bytes:16437 (16.4 KB)
```

Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: f0:de:f1:8c:99:da
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 memory:f2500000-f251ffff memory:f252b000-f252bfff ioport:6080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 74:de:2b:0d:90:8a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=3.13.0-45-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:f2400000-f2403fff
```

Here is the output of `ipconfig /all` in windows:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Explorer
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 1x1 11b/g/n Wireless LAN PCI Express Half
 Mini Card Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 74-DE-2B-0D-90-8A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connecti
on
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : F0-DE-F1-8C-99-DA
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:1620:2018:1c:5c6d:939e:a030:23b2(Pre
ferred)
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2001:1620:2018:1c:6de5:ffa5:cced:3911(Pre
ferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5c6d:939e:a030:23b2%10(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 82.197.169.178(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.192
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 15 February 2015 12:14:45
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 15 February 2015 23:14:44
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::768e:f8ff:fe74:6500%10
                                       82.197.169.129
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 77.109.140.198
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 77.109.128.2
                                       213.144.129.20
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{52B632EE-432C-43F8-8127-3CB90FFACBD6}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{34F5D21C-C5B4-414E-8C3C-BACEA03584CB}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6abd:12:3cb9:ad3a:564d(Prefer
red)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::12:3cb9:ad3a:564d%12(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you ping just no URL web addresses or no raw IP addresses either? Try a `ping 109.193.193.29` (which is google.com). If you get results, it is an DNS fault.

Comment: I get `Network is unreachable`

Comment: Can you ping your local router/gateway? It should be address 82.197.169.129 or fe80::768e:f8ff:fe74:6500%10. Or try all the other IPv4 and IPv6 addresses in your Windows output (Subnet Mask 255.255.255.192 is NOT an address!)

Comment: All the ipv4 ones say network is unreachable, all the ipv6 ones say "unknown host".

Comment: I just tried disabling ipv6 and I can ping google now. So maybe now it is a DNS issue?

Comment: OK as well as disabling IPv6 I created the file /etc/resolv.conf with the line `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and now it works somehow. So that's good and I'm finally operational now. But ideally I'd like a solution where I don't have to disable IPv6.

Comment: You should edit your question and mention the IPv4/v6 stuff there (maybe even in the title), to attract the right people who know about this.